# How to do ad pass though authentication with rest api

Tags: c#, rest, active-directory

I get how to do authentication with LDAP using a password and user name with a rest API. But need to allow the user to auto login using the active directory pass through like SharePoint does.

I have no idea how to do this and can't find any material on how.

I used c# .net for the rest API in visual studio.